# Cómo obtener el valor de un input type radio con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con una plantilla que compré y tiene el siguiente código en HTML.

```js
$( "#estrellas1 input" ).change(function() {
  var valorestrella = $("#rating1 input").val(); 
  alert(valorestrella);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="rating-star" >
    <div class="rating" id="estrellas1">
      <input type="radio" id="i1e5" name="rating1" ><label class="full" for="i1e5"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="i1e4" name="rating1"><label class="full" for="i1e4"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="i1e3" name="rating1"><label class="full" for="i1e3"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="i1e2" name="rating1"><label class="full" for="i1e2"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="i1e1" name="rating1""><label class="full" for="i1e1"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Deseo obtener el valor del input, ya sea 1,2,3,4 o 5 para guardarlo.

Actualmente estoy testeando este código con `JQuery` , pero estoy obteniendo un valor indefinido :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he tratado de diferentes maneras sin éxito alguno. Ojalá alguien me pueda orientar a detectar mi error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, no tiene asignado el atributo `value` en los input para poder acceder con `val()`, además debe tener en cuenta que el elemento en el cuál se produjo el evento se puede referenciar por la palabra reservada `this`.

Además recomiendo ser más especifico con el elemento que dese escuchar el evento  `input` es muy general y visto que no tiene una clase que compartan todos, los seleccione por el `name` `input[type="nameradio"]` para el ejemplo, entonces su código podría quedar de la siguiente forma

```js
$( "#estrellas1 input[name='rating1']" ).change(function() {
  var valorestrella = $(this).val(); 
  console.log(valorestrella);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" id="estrellas1">
<input type="radio" id="i1e5" name="rating1"  value="1"><label class="full" for="i1e5"></label>
<input type="radio" id="i1e4" name="rating1" value="2"><label class="full" for="i1e4"></label>
<input type="radio" id="i1e3" name="rating1" value="3"><label class="full" for="i1e3"></label>
<input type="radio" id="i1e2" name="rating1" value="4"><label class="full" for="i1e2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="i1e1" name="rating1" value="5"><label class="full" for="i1e1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Estoy tan agotado con el proyecto que efectivamente olvidé agregarle el valor, me da mucha pena, como pude pasar desperdiciado algo tan básico. Muchas gracias, eres genial Joel.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta suele pasar, tranquilo y a seguir :) , Ah y si resolvió el problema puedes marcarla como aceptada . Saludos.

Comment: Es verdad, perdona lo había olvidado. Ya quedó, infinitamente agradecido.